# Problem in making the items in RecyclerView clickable

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I know there are questions like this, but non solving mine..

I'm trying to make 'OnItemClickListener' of 'RecyclerView' , but when I run the app it stops..

can you tell me where is the error??

Here is the code: (Note the error is in making the item clickable)

```
public class TeacherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private FirebaseAuth mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
private FirebaseUser currentUser= mAuth.getCurrentUser();;
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private String UserId =currentUser.getUid();
private static String city;
private TeacherAdapter teacherAdapter;
public static final String EXTRA_PATH = "com.example.exercise.EXTRA_PATH";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_teacher);


    setUpRecyclerView();


  teacherAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new TeacherAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {

    String path = documentSnapshot.getReference().getPath();
    Intent intent = new Intent(TeacherActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PATH, path);
    startActivity(intent);

    }
    });

}// end of onCreate


private void setUpRecyclerView(){
    Query query =   db.collection("Teachers");

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions < Teacher > options = new 
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Teacher>()
                            .setQuery(query, Teacher.class)
                            .build();

    teacherAdapter = new TeacherAdapter(options);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);    //for performane reasons
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(teacherAdapter);
    teacherAdapter.startListening();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    teacherAdapter.stopListening();
}

}// end of class
```

And this is the 'adapter' of 'RecyclerView':

```
public class TeacherAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Teacher, 
TeacherAdapter.TeacherHolder> {
private OnItemClickListener listener;
public TeacherAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Teacher> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TeacherHolder holder, int i, @NonNull Teacher 
teacher) {
    holder.tv_teacher_name.setText(teacher.getName());
    holder.tv_cv.setText(teacher.getCv());
}

@NonNull
@Override
public TeacherHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.teacher_item, parent, false);
    return new TeacherHolder(v);
}

class TeacherHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_teacher_name;
    TextView tv_cv;


 public TeacherHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv_teacher_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.teacher_name);
        tv_cv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cv);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null){
                    listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
}
public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}
}
```

Part of logcat:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.exercise, PID: 29966
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.exercise/com.example.exercise.TeacherActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.exercise.TeacherAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(com.example.exercise.TeacherAdapter$OnItemClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: what does logcat say when the app crashes

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo this is part of logcat, thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.exercise, PID: 29966 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.exercise/com.example.exercise.TeacherActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.exercise.TeacherAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(com.example.exercise.TeacherAdapter$OnItemClickListener)' on a null object reference

Because you are calling `.setOnItemClickListener()` on your `teacherAdapter` object which is `null` at that point in time. To solve this, you should simply move the following block of code:

```
teacherAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new TeacherAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {

        String path = documentSnapshot.getReference().getPath();
        Intent intent = new Intent(TeacherActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PATH, path);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Right after the declaration of your adapter:

```
teacherAdapter = new TeacherAdapter(options);
```

In your `setUpRecyclerView()` method and your problem will be solved.

Comment: hi could you help me out here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76786965/facing-issue-while-validating-amongst-the-edittexts-in-recyclerview